# Deleting elements dynamically from ng-repeat generated list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having an array of json objects which have nested arrays. I am using ng-repeat to create list with those nested arrays. I want to delete the items from list dynamically on button click. I have written a function in controller to do that-

```
$scope.remove= function(path){
    var obj = $scope.results[$scope.editIndex];

    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<path.length-1;i++){

        var key = path[i].key;
        var index = path[i].index;
        if(!obj[key]) return;
        obj = obj[key]

    }
    delete obj[path[i].key][path[i].index];

}
```

and calling it like-

```
<ul ng-show="showFeatures">
   <li ng-repeat="(featureIndex,feature) in result.features">
        <span ng-bind="feature" contenteditable={{result.edit}}></span>
            <i class="flr-always material-icons pointer" ng-show="result.edit" ng-click="remove([{key:'features',index:featureIndex}])">delete</i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Problem is that I can not delete more than one element, as after first element indexes will change in array, but ng-repeat does not changes index in its scope. How can I solve this problem ? Can I make ng-repeat, re plot itself after I make any change
I am just learning angular js, so please guide me if there is a better way to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="(featureIndex,feature) in result.features">
        <span ng-bind="feature" contenteditable={{result.edit}}></span>
            <i class="flr-always material-icons pointer" ng-show="result.edit" ng-click="remove([{key:'features',index:featureIndex}])">delete</i>
 </li>
```

Here **result.features** is an array. So send **$index** from AngularJS template which will correspond to the array index which you want to delete. 
e.g., ng-click="remove($index)"
then in controller

```
function remove(index){
    $scope.result.features.splice($index, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <li ng-repeat="feature in result.features">
    <span ng-bind="feature" contenteditable={{result.edit}}></span>
        <i class="flr-always material-icons pointer" ng-show="result.edit" ng-click="remove(feature )">delete</i>
 </li>
```

and in remove function

```
   function remove(feature){
     var index = $scope.result.features.indexOf(feature);
      if(index > -1)
       $scope.result.features.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app",  []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.result = {
                    features:
                      [
                        "ali","reza","amir"
                     ]
                 };
  
  
    $scope.remove = function(feature){
     var index = $scope.result.features.indexOf(feature);
      if(index > -1)
       $scope.result.features.splice(index, 1);
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <li ng-repeat="feature in result.features">
        <span ng-bind="feature"></span>
        <i  ng-click="remove(feature)">delete</i>
     </li> 
</div>
```

Comment: Array index of features will change in json object.